# get only pure non numeric elements from column pandas

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe, data-manipulation

I have a data column like this:

```
   Phrase

   A4678LM
   AFNH
   2l6m8
   2312435
   122
   ABC
   HOW
   IS
   Pa805
```

and so on. Now this is a column in a dataframe in python. I want to select only the pure non-numeric values such as:

```
  Phrase

   AFNH
   ABC
   HOW
   IS
```

The column contains only pure non numeric values. The type of my pandas column is

> Phrase:                object type

I tried using this formula:

```
df.applymap(np.isreal)
```

but I couldnt get the result. I was showing all as FALSE.
How to i get only the pure non-numeric values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the code below:

`df[df['Phrase'].str.match("^[a-zA-Z]+$")]`

It checks every row for alphabets only, if it contains, then picks it.

Answer (score 1):

Using `str.contains`

```
df[~df.Phrase.str.contains('\d+')]
Out[780]: 
  Phrase
1   AFNH
5    ABC
6    HOW
7     IS
```